# How to cancel a deferred statement

Tags: go, mutex

I have the following code structure where I Lock() at point A and need to definitely Unlock() at a point B in the same function. Between point A and B, I have multiple returns based on errors where I would need to Unlock(). Using `defer lock.Unlock()` at point A solves the problem that in case there are errors the lock would be released. However, if execution successfully reaches point B - how can I cancel that defer and Unlock() anyway?

```golang
func foo() {
    ...
    // point A
    lock.Lock()
    defer lock.Unlock()
    ...
    err := bar()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    ...
    //point B - need to definetely unlock here
    //lock.Unlock() ?
}
```

Comment: At point B, the defer will run which will "definitely unlock." You shouldn't code around that; that just makes your code asymmetrical and error-prone, undermining the whole point of using defer. If for some reason "point B" isn't the end of the scope that fires the defer, redesign so that it is.

Comment: Put everything between A and B into its own function. You can use an anonymous closure if you want: https://play.golang.org/p/Wj4xXNiCfiZ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't cancel a deferred function.

You could use `sync.Once` to ensure that the mutex is unlocked exactly once:

```
func foo() {
    var unlockOnce sync.Once

    // point A
    lock.Lock()
    defer unlockOnce.Do(lock.Unlock)
    ...
    err := bar()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    ...
    // point B - need to unlock here
    unlockOnce.Do(lock.Unlock)
}
```

If possible, it is probably better to refactor your code so that the locked portion remains in a single function:

```
func fooLock() error {
    lock.Lock()
    defer lock.Unlock()
    if err := bar(); err != nil { return err }
    ...
    return nil
}

func foo() {
    if err := fooLock(); err != nil { return }
    ... do the bit that doesn't need a lock
}
```

Obviously naming and error handling here is lax because the code is generic and not specific. If you need information from the block of code before your point B, which is now in code in `fooLock`, it can be returned along with the error.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to cancel a deferred function.

Use a local variable to record the function's state with respect to the lock and check that variable in the deferred function.

```
lock.Lock()
locked := true

defer func() {
    if locked  {
        lock.Unlock()
    }
}()
...
err := bar()
if err != nil {
    return
}
...

lock.Unlock()
locked = false

...
```

Because locks are generally used in a multithreaded environment, it should be noted that the function local variable `locked` should only accessed by a single goroutine (thank you Rick-777 for calling this out in a comment).

Comment: If this code is executed again, I will have to initialize the lock again right? Seems like I will have to let go using defer and just release lock explicitly before every return. @CeriseLimón

Comment: +1 for this answer. One extra precaution: be sure the flag `locked` (or whatever you call it) must not be [accidentally] accessed by multiple goroutines.